# Существует ли понятие семантического окказионализма, а если нет то как его правильно назвать?

Tags: лингвистика

Мне встретилась фраза *"Рояль должен быть исчезнут"*, и мне стало интересно как правильно классифицировать в ней глагол *"исчезнуть"*.

Если бы измененное значение глагола было распространенным - это был бы неологизм образованный семантической деривацией, но это всего лишь авторская придумка. Но как окказионализм его тоже классифицировать не получается, потому что доступные мне источники описывают окказионализм исключительно как новое слово построенное по правилам словообразования, а новый смысл существующего слова под определение окказионализма не подходит.

Comment: как курьёз?....

Comment: Мне кажется, я схожу с ума, когда читаю ваш вопрос :)

Comment: существует, а если не существует - то можно назвать семантическим окказионализмом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используется понятие **грамматического** (морфологического) **окказионализма**.

Статья: "Грамматические окказионализмы в авторском тексте":

https://narfu.ru/university/library/books/1058.pdf

*Семантический окказионализм* означает другое:

https://studfiles.net/preview/383843/page:7/

Comment: Спасибо, это я и искал. Кстати, забавно - пока я не перешел по вашим ссылкам, гугл выдавал по запросу *"Семантический окказионализм"* какую-то ерунду...

Answer (score -1):

я конечно не филолог и не лингвист, но посмотреть могу 8^)

Вот [здесь](https://publications.hse.ru/chapters/102333542), например, речь идёт о таких понятиях, как "*переходность*" и "*лабильность*" глаголов. "Переходность" в смысле способности быть переходными, каковым стал глагол `исчезнуть` в приведённой фразе. А "*лабильность*" в смысле способности глаголов быть как переходными, так и непереходными без формальных изменений, точно как в случае приведённой фразы.

В другой просмотренной [литературе](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=JlyTCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA275&lpg=PA275&dq=%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=hj97BYadOk&sig=i_cMzr6LTnbDXXm6qD6dlTcuTD4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj1m7CC3ZXYAhXBYlAKHcBCB5kQ6AEINjAC#v=onepage&q=%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0&f=false) процесс изменения формы глаголов между переходной и непереходной называется "*лабилизацией*".

Стало быть глагол `исчезнут` в приведённой фразе можно, вероятно, классифицировать как "*призвольно лабилизированный, в страдательном залоге*". Это, конечно, не научная классификация, а всего лишь попытка её произвести.

Покопавшись ещё в [литературе](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=7U7TAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA342&lpg=PA342&dq=%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%20%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=RxT-1ffGVX&sig=zLfs6B800BzVGyTZgEGp2jfFyWo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYrc7a5pXYAhWSLlAKHeF8AWYQ6AEISzAF#v=onepage&q=%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3%20%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0&f=false), нашёл термин "*[семантический сдвиг](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B3)*" (хотя и без его связи с явлением лабильности глаголов) которому приведённый пример может удовлетворять.

Comment: Спасибо за описание умными словами о том что именно *произошло* с глалогом. Но меня интересует как назвать что в итоге *получилось*.

Comment: обновил ответ...